# How can I deprecate an old version of my custom Gutenberg block, but keep the new version?

Tags: block-editor

In the event that a custom block that is already deployed on the site needs to be updated, I'd like to do so in a way that doesn't trigger the 'This block has invalid content' error.

I found that this is possible by adding a deprecated property to the registerBlockType function. However, adding this property creates a new error which says:

```
Your site doesn’t include support for the "toms/first-block" block.
You can leave this block intact, convert its content to a Custom HTML block, or remove it entirely.
```

This is my code:
index.js

```
/**
 * Registers a new block provided a unique name and an object defining its behavior.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-registration/
 */
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';

/**
 * Lets webpack process CSS, SASS or SCSS files referenced in JavaScript files.
 * All files containing `style` keyword are bundled together. The code used
 * gets applied both to the front of your site and to the editor.
 *
 * @see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts#using-css
 */
import './style.scss';

/**
 * Internal dependencies
 */
import Edit from './edit';
import save from './save';
import metadata from './block.json';

/**
 * Every block starts by registering a new block type definition.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-registration/
 */
registerBlockType( metadata.name, {
    /**
     * @see ./edit.js
     */
    edit: Edit,

    /**
     * @see ./save.js
     */
    save,
    deprecated: [
        {
            attributes,

            save( props ) {
                return (
                    <>
                        <h3>{ props.attributes.morecontent }</h3>
                        <p>{props.attributes.content}</p>
                    </>
                );
            },
        },
    ],
} );
```

edit.js

```
/**
 * Retrieves the translation of text.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-i18n/
 */
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { BlockToolbar } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

const MyBlockToolbar = () => <BlockToolbar />;
/**
 * React hook that is used to mark the block wrapper element.
 * It provides all the necessary props like the class name.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-block-editor/#useblockprops
 */
import { useBlockProps, RichText, BlockControls } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

/**
 * Lets webpack process CSS, SASS or SCSS files referenced in JavaScript files.
 * Those files can contain any CSS code that gets applied to the editor.
 *
 * @see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts#using-css
 */
import './editor.scss';

/**
 * The edit function describes the structure of your block in the context of the
 * editor. This represents what the editor will render when the block is used.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/#edit
 *
 * @return {WPElement} Element to render.
 */
export default function Edit(props) {
    const {attributes, setAttributes} = props;
    return (
        <>
        <MyBlockToolbar />
        <RichText
        tagName='h2'
        value={attributes.morecontent}
        onChange={(morecontent)=>setAttributes({morecontent})}
        placeholder = 'Type Content Here'
        />
        <RichText
        tagName='p'
        value={attributes.content}
        onChange={(content)=>setAttributes({content})}
        placeholder = 'Type Content Here'
        />
        </>
    );
}
```

save.js

```
/**
 * React hook that is used to mark the block wrapper element.
 * It provides all the necessary props like the class name.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-block-editor/#useblockprops
 */
import { useBlockProps, RichText } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

/**
 * The save function defines the way in which the different attributes should
 * be combined into the final markup, which is then serialized by the block
 * editor into `post_content`.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/#save
 *
 * @return {WPElement} Element to render.
 */
export default function save(props) {
    const {attributes} = props;
    return (
        <>
        <RichText.Content
        tagName='h2'
        value={attributes.morecontent}
        />
        <RichText.Content
        tagName='p'
        value={attributes.content}
        />
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Is your block triggering an error in the browser console? Does it work again if you remove the `deprecated` property? Is the content of the `deprecated->save` exactly the same as the previous function?

Comment: Thank you for reminding me to check SCRIPT_DEBUG on. That tipped me off to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake I made was that I didn't set the attribute property in the deprecated block to the proper value. I have to assign the expected attributes here, just as I did in block.json. If the attributes changed, I'd put the old attributes here. Since they did not change, I used the current value of attributes from block.json.

My fixed index.js file:

```
/**
 * Registers a new block provided a unique name and an object defining its behavior.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-registration/
 */
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';

/**
 * Lets webpack process CSS, SASS or SCSS files referenced in JavaScript files.
 * All files containing `style` keyword are bundled together. The code used
 * gets applied both to the front of your site and to the editor.
 *
 * @see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts#using-css
 */
import './style.scss';

/**
 * Internal dependencies
 */
import Edit from './edit';
import save from './save';
import metadata from './block.json';

/**
 * Every block starts by registering a new block type definition.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-registration/
 */
registerBlockType( metadata.name, {
    /**
     * @see ./edit.js
     */
    edit: Edit,

    /**
     * @see ./save.js
     */
    save,
    deprecated: [
        {
            attributes: metadata.attributes,

            save( props ) {
                return (
                    <>
                        <h3>{ props.attributes.morecontent }</h3>
                        <p>{props.attributes.content}</p>
                    </>
                );
            },
        },
    ],
} );
```